# android black screen when get phone contacts

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to get all contacts from phone but when I use it that cause of black screen.

Thread :

```
        Thread getAllContacts = new Thread () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                runOnUiThread ( new Runnable () {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        getContacts ( getContentResolver () );
                    }
                } );
            }
        };
        getAllContacts.start ();
```

And this below code is my `getContacts` method, I can not update it to have fast way to get contacts:

```
public void getContacts(ContentResolver cr){
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String id          = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
        String name        = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Bitmap photo       = G.getContactPhoto ( phoneNumber, getContentResolver () );

        ContactListStructure item = new ContactListStructure();
        String phone_number = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\s+","").trim ().replace("+98", "0");
        int check_mobile = phone_number.indexOf ( "09" );
        if( check_mobile != -1){
            item.id = Long.parseLong ( id );
            item.name = name;
            item.mobile = phone_number;
            item.photo = photo;
            item.checked = false;
            G.contact_item.add ( item );
            //personlst.add( new Person (item.name, item.mobile) );
        }
    }
    phones.close ();
}
```

Comment: probably because you running the `getContacts` method on the UI thread.

Comment: You might not have the permission to read them. Stacktrace?

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić i dont have any problem to read contacts but speed of that is low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see your problem.
You are running it on the UI thread.
Create an AsyncTask and run it there. When the tash is complete use the runOnUIThread method to display the contacts.

Comment: Please vote up. I need it to get my asking ability back.